# Call to a database in the link directory

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to do a VBA SQL call to a database in the link directory

The database is held in Sync drive, but my local link is listed below and correct

When I try open the program it comes up with

> Run-time error 3024 - Could not find the File Powershop.mdb

```
ChDir "C:\Users\User\Sync\Powershop Backups\GI"


ReadOnly = False

'      >>>>> Open Database <<<<<

Set Jet = CreateWorkspace("", "admin", "", dbUseJet)
Set PowerShop = Jet.OpenDatabase("PowerShop.mdb", , ReadOnly)
```

Comment: Don't use `ChDir` - Instead, use the full path to the database in the `OpenDatabase` line.

Comment: And verify that the database is actually in that location.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - We have hundreds of database calls so not possible

Comment: "Not possible" makes no sense. well, good luck.

Comment: Possible, but not practical for our situation due to so many different versions we have

Comment: Use a function that accepts your "different versions" as parameters.

Comment: You can jsut use a global variable for the path instead, and then do a global string replace for each line that updates it to the new way. It would take 2 minutes max.

Answer (score 1):

Use a With block for database connections so the object always gets cleaned up properly. This makes it so you don't have to manually set Jet = nothing at some point.

Like so:

```
Dim thePath As String
thePath = "C:\Users\User\Sync\Powershop Backups\GI\"
With Jet.OpenDatabase(thePath & "PowerShop.mdb", , ReadOnly)

    ' Do stuff with the database 

    .Close
End With
```